# Parameterizing a dynamic SQL statement

Tags: c#, sql

When I run the following code I get an error: "Must declare the scalar variable "@objString"".  Can I not parameterize a dynamic SQL statement?  Is there a better way of writing this?  I had it working but it involved dynamically inserting the *name* and *userID* which is obviously a security issue as that information is passed in from an end user web page.  I would like to parameterize those two values to avoid SQL injection issues.

```
    private void setValue(Object obj, String name)
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = SQLConnections.GetPortalConnection();
        String sqlStatement = String.Empty;
        string[] parameterNames;
        string[] parameters;

        switch (obj.GetType().ToString())
        {
            case "System.String":
                string objString = obj.ToString();
                sqlStatement = @"
                                declare @name nvarchar(" + name.Length + @");
                                declare @sql nvarchar(4000); 
                                SET @name = '" + name + @"';
                                SET @sql = 'UPDATE [myoc4Data].[dbo].[users] SET ' + @name + ' = @objString WHERE [UserID] = @userID;'
                                exec sp_executesql @sql;";
                string[] parameterNames = { "@objString", "@userID" };
                string[] parameters = { objString, this.userID };
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Person.Portal.UserProfile.setValue: object type not found");
        }

        SQLConnections.ExecuteNonQuery(sqlStatement, parameterNames, parameters, sqlConnection);
        sqlConnection.Close();
    }
```

...

```
    public static void ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlStatement, string[] parameterNames, object[] parameters, SqlConnection sqlConnection)
    {
        // Parameterized query
        try
        {
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
            sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, sqlConnection);
            for (int x = 0; x < parameters.Length; x++)
            {
                switch (Type.GetTypeCode(parameters[x].GetType()))
                {
                    case TypeCode.DateTime:
                        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(parameterNames[x], SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = ((DateTime)parameters[x]).Year < 1753 ? DBNull.Value : parameters[x];
                        continue;
                }
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(parameterNames[x], parameters[x]));
            }
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentException("Exception: Person: SQLConnections: Could not execute SQL statement: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not create a stored procedure instead of hacky SQL concatenation?

Comment: Josh take a look here this is much easier to understand and it's actually a better approach in regards to letting the Database Server determine the Datatype of the ParameterValue you are passing in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx

Comment: I can't see any reference to `@question`. Are you sure the posted code is correct?

Comment: for your table creation and UPDATE statements to avoid potential SQL Injection, write / create a `Stored Procedure`

Comment: I'm sorry I was trying to hack the code together so it made since on here and messed it up.  I think it is fixed now.  Should make more since.  I will look into stored procedures.  DJ I will look at your link.  Yes userID is a string.

Comment: I can recommend using iBatis .NET which has good query building capabilities. Preventing SQL injection is precisely one goal of the framework.

See http://ibatis.apache.org/docs/dotnet/datamapper/ch03s09.html

Comment: @DJKRAZE, AddWithValue might trash your plan cache since the parameter size is set to the size of the argument, i.e. plans will not be reused for different sizes of the argument. Second, varchars will not be truncated and might cause an sql error if the value is to big for the target field. Use `Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, sizeofdatabasefield).Value = name`

Comment: I've never once had a problem using AddWithValue sorry..

Comment: Is your parameter's value null? If so, you need to use DBNull.Value instead